# Merge multiple csv files in one excel sheet

Tags: excel, file, vba, csv, merge

After searching a lot on the internet i tried to combine a working Excel VBA code that reads all .csv files in a folder into an excel file (each on a seperate worksheet).
But the only thing i need is to combine all the csv files in 1 worksheet....

The working code is:

---

### working file into seperate worksheets

```
Sub Example12()
Dim MyPath As String
Dim FilesInPath As String
Dim MyFiles() As String
Dim SourceRcount As Long
Dim Fnum As Long
Dim mybook As Workbook
Dim basebook As Workbook

'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
'on your machine
MyPath = "c:\Data"

'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
MyPath = MyPath & "\"
End If

'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.csv")
If FilesInPath = "" Then
MsgBox "No files found"
Exit Sub
End If

On Error GoTo CleanUp

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set basebook = ThisWorkbook

'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
Fnum = 0
Do While FilesInPath <> ""
Fnum = Fnum + 1
ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
FilesInPath = Dir()
Loop

'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
If Fnum > 0 Then
For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
mybook.Worksheets(1).Copy after:= _
basebook.Sheets(basebook.Sheets.Count)

On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Name = mybook.Name
On Error GoTo 0

' You can use this if you want to copy only the values
' With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
' .Value = .Value
' End With

mybook.Close savechanges:=False
Next Fnum
End If
CleanUp:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
---------------------------------------------------------

But the change i've made was to change the part where the VBA copies it into a sheet "after" the last one, to append it to a existing sheet "Totaal".
```

---

```
not working code
---------------------------------------------------------

Sub Example12()
Dim MyPath As String
Dim FilesInPath As String
Dim MyFiles() As String
Dim SourceRcount As Long
Dim Fnum As Long
Dim mybook As Workbook
Dim basebook As Workbook

'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
'on your machine
MyPath = "c:\Data"

'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
MyPath = MyPath & "\"
End If

'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.csv")
If FilesInPath = "" Then
MsgBox "No files found"
Exit Sub
End If

On Error GoTo CleanUp

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set basebook = ThisWorkbook

'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
Fnum = 0
Do While FilesInPath <> ""
Fnum = Fnum + 1
ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
FilesInPath = Dir()
Loop

'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
If Fnum > 0 Then
For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
mybook.Worksheets(1).Copy

**basebook.Sheets("Totaal").Select
NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 0).End(xlUp).Row
Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste**

On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Name = mybook.Name
On Error GoTo 0

' You can use this if you want to copy only the values
' With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = .Value
' End With

mybook.Close savechanges:=False
Next Fnum
End If
CleanUp:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

I haven't got the knowledge to change this :(. 
Was I on the right track?

All input will be greatly appreciated!

EXTRA INFO: The data in the CSV files are put in the first column. After the whole merging process i planned to do the split into columns afterwards....

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After  `Set basebook = ThisWorkbook`

Enter this:

```
Dim nextRow As Integer
Dim wsTotal As Worksheet
Set wsTotal = basebook.Worksheets("Total")
```

And here is the corrected For loop:

```
'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
If Fnum > 0 Then
    For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)

        'open file
        Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))

        With wsTotal

            'activate if you want (optional)
            '.Activate

            'copy all the data on the sheet
            mybook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Copy

            'find the next empty row
            nextRow = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1

            'select if desired (optional)
            '.Cells(NextRow, 1).Select

            'paste the data
            .Cells(nextRow, 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

            'turn off copy mode
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            'Do you really want to change the worksheet name?
            .Name = mybook.Name
        End With

        'close file
        mybook.Close savechanges:=False

    Next Fnum
```

Comment: It doesn't work after these changes. It only opens 1 sheet and removes the Total sheet.

Comment: Use the debugger; press F8 to step through the code and see what is not working. Use Debug.Print to see what the variables are. I understood you only wanted one sheet. Also it doesn't remove the Total sheet; it just renames it. If you don't want that then remove that line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will check this tomorrow.

Indeed i want to merge all csv files into 1 sheet. But in this case he imported 1 csv, renamed the sheet from Total to the name of the csv file and then stopped. I will dive into it tomorrow when i have more time for it! 

Thanks again for responding!

Comment: I commented out this line of code. Then the whole process went very well !!

'Do you really want to change the worksheet name?
            .Name = mybook.Name

Answer (score 0):

To import csv files I would suggest using a query instead of opening them. This way, you can also perform the data-to-columns split on-the-go :

```
Sub ImportToNewWorksheet(ImpFileName as String)
 Dim mySheet As Worksheet
 Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
 Call ImportFile(ImpFileName, mySheet.Cells(1,1))
End Sub

Sub ImportFile(ImpFileName As String, ImpDest As Range)
 With ImpDest.Worksheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
  "TEXT;" & ImpFileName, Destination:=ImpDest)
  .Name = "Import"
  .FieldNames = True
  .RowNumbers = False
  .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
  .PreserveFormatting = True
  .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
  .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
  .SavePassword = False
  .SaveData = True
  .AdjustColumnWidth = True
  .RefreshPeriod = 0
  .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
  .TextFilePlatform = 65001
  .TextFileStartRow = 1
  .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
  .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
  .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
  .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
  .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
  .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
  .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
  .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1)
  .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
  .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
 End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I am going to look into this.. It looks like a better solution, but i don't know how to implement this in my code at the moment.