# excel vba macro to merge csv files into a new excel worksheet and removing subsequent headers which are 3 lines

Tags: excel, vba

I started with the code here:([Merge multiple csv files in one excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654088/merge-multiple-csv-files-in-one-excel-sheet))

```
 Sub Example12()
 Dim MyPath As String
 Dim FilesInPath As Variant
 Dim MyFiles() As String
 Dim SourceRcount As Long
 Dim Fnum As Long
 Dim mybook As Workbook
 Dim basebook As Workbook

'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
 'on your machine
 MyPath = " C:\Users\Downloads\merge"

 'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
 If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
 MyPath = MyPath & "\"
 End If

'If there are no csv files in the folder exit the sub
 FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.csv")
 If FilesInPath = "" Then
 MsgBox "No files found"
 Exit Sub
 End If


On Error GoTo CleanUp

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set basebook = ThisWorkbook
Dim nextRow As Integer
Dim wsTotal As Worksheet
Set wsTotal = basebook.Worksheets("Total")


'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
 Fnum = 0     
 Do While FilesInPath <> ""
 Fnum = Fnum + 1
 ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
 MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
 FilesInPath = Dir()
 Loop

 'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
 If Fnum > 0 Then
 For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)

    'open file
    Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))

    With wsTotal

        'activate if you want (optional)
        '.Activate

        'copy all the data on the sheet
        mybook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Copy

        'find the next empty row
        nextRow = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1

        'select if desired (optional)
        '.Cells(NextRow, 1).Select

        'paste the data
        .Cells(nextRow, 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

        'turn off copy mode
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        'Do you really want to change the worksheet name?
        .Name = mybook.Name
    End With

    'close file
    mybook.Close savechanges:=False

   Next Fnum
   End If
   CleanUp:
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   End Sub
```

I am not sure what is happening but it runs without errors,but i dont see any result. I was also not sure where it was suppose to create my excel file(name of the file)with all the text from CSV files. My csv files have number of column names which repeat in all my csv files and also have sheet name same as the csv files name (like Document_15679990 etc) which may be the issue. I wanted to change the code to have the ability to select the files in the folder rather than all the files,but got errors using below code-type mismatch and changed FilesinPath to variant but still got errors further in the code.

```
  FilesInPath = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv", , "Select CSV Files", "Select", True)
```

I also wanted to remove the 3 line headers that repeat subsequently.Any explanation of where does it create the excel worksheet and with what name or is it exiting the sub?and few changes to the code to fulfil my requirements is greatly appreciated.

Comment: the simpliest  : Shell("cmd /c copy  *.csv all.csv", vbNormalFocus)

Comment: I wrote this code but what it is doing is just opening the command window with the location mentioned. I need to type this command there copy .csv all.csv how do i change code to do this by itself.                      ' Sub merge() Dim vPID As Variant Dim myPath As Variant myPath = "C:\Users\Downloads\merge" vPID = Shell("cmd \c copy" & myPath & ".csv" & myPath & "all.csv", vbNormalFocus) End Sub ' also how can I remove the repeated 3 line headers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is your problem but

```
nextRow = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1
```

can give you a wrong result.

If you write into a cell, also if you clear it, that cell will be counted by `xlCellTypeLastCell`

This code will show you the error you could get:

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
ws.Name = "TmpSheet"
With ws
    a = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    MsgBox ("LastCell Is: " & a & vbCrLf & "Now I'll insert some data")
    .Range("A5") = "Test"
    .Range("B9") = "Test"
    MsgBox ("Now I'll clear inserted data")
    .Range("A5:B9").Clear
    a = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    MsgBox ("Now LastCell Is: " & a)
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ws.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

So try using a column where you are sure to have last row filled and use:

```
nextRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Change "B" to your column
```